# Appending objects to a list; Performing function is giving Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I was writing my code for a problem this error occurred:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'someMethod'`
when I had my object clearly defined.

My code looks something like this:

```
#Assuming that someObject has method "someMethod"
otherList = []
for someObject in listOfObjects:
    if someObject.someMethod() != True:
        otherList.append(someObject)
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your `listOfObjects`?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `append` method, you have a `None` in your `listOfObjects`

Comment: You guys are right. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Side-note: Don't do `if someObject.someMethod() != True:`; unless there is a really strong motivation, you should do implicit truthiness testing for "truthy" or "falsy", which in this case would be `if not someObject.someMethod():`. It means `someMethod` is not constrained to only returning `True` to indicate truth; if it calculates a `list` of results, it can return the `list` directly (allows caller to use the contents, or just test for truthiness). [Per PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Selcuk already mentioned you have a `None` in your `listOfObjects`. To catch this case you can check if they have this method by using:

```
#Assuming that someObject has method "someMethod"
otherList = []
for someObject in listOfObjects:
    if getattr(someObject, 'someMethod', lambda : True)() != True:
        otherList.append(someObject)
```

`getattr` will try to get the method and if it has no such method it will return a function that will return `True` if called. An alternative is just to catch these Exceptions:

```
#Assuming that someObject has method "someMethod"
otherList = []
for someObject in listOfObjects:
    try:
        if someObject.someMethod() != True:
            otherList.append(someObject)
    except AttributeError():
        # Catch the Error but just let it go, we wouldn't want to append it.
        pass
```

---

Just as an aside, if you **know** there is no such problem with `None` in the list there is a nice alternative to your loop:

```
import itertools
import operator
otherList = list(itertools.filterfalse(operator.methodcaller('someMethod'), listOfObjects))
```

might be that you need to replace `filterfalse` by [`ifilterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse) with python2

Even though it will only keep the elements that return `False` and not like you specified `!= True` but I thought it's a nice alternative considering that the itertools and operator are faster than normal iterations.